# Automatically adjust title image in beamer (beamerinnertheme.sty)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I'm trying to create my own beamer theme and am failing at something probably simple. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out at all and hope that someone has a solution for me.
As you can see from the title, it's about the cover image of a beamer theme that I want to create myself.

In beamerinnertheme.sty I have already specified, with the help of the community here, that a default image is taken if no title image has been chosen.

But now I would like to add to the code or have the option of selecting a title image in the presentation.tex file, which is automatically adapted to the frame and of course also to the selected aspectratio.

In other words, in the presentation.tex e.g.. For example, the command:

`\titlepicture{file}`

and it automatically appears in the right place via innertheme.

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=1609,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage {mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}
%\titlegraphic{example-image-a}

%beamertheme.sty
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%beamercolortheme.sty
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{framtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}

%beamerinnertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {\hspace{4cm}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
       \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
       \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
       \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
       \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
       \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
       \fi     
   \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 1}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 2}
   \begin{frame}{Title 2}
       \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty` you are already testing if your user set the `\titlegraphic` macro. You can use the else branch of this test to replace your default image with the image chosen by the user.

I would not automatically adapt the aspect ratio. In almost all cases this will distort the image. Let the user decide how big they want their image to be.

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=1609,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

%beamertheme.sty
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%beamercolortheme.sty
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{framtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}

%beamerinnertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {\hspace{4cm}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
       \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
       \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
       \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
       \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
         \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
       \else
        \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\inserttitlegraphic};
       \fi     
   \end{tikzpicture}   
}


\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 1}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 2}
   \begin{frame}{Title 2}
       \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively if you want to clip the image so that you see the centre of the image:

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=1609,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

%beamertheme.sty
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%beamercolortheme.sty
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{framtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}

%beamerinnertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {\hspace{4cm}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
       \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
       \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
       \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
       \begin{scope}
         \clip ([yshift=3cm]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
         \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
           \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
         \else
          \node[inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=1.5cm]current page.center) {\inserttitlegraphic};
         \fi     
       \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 1}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}
   \section{Sec 2}
   \begin{frame}{Title 2}
       \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for sharing this with me. What if I ignored your advice. Would it be possible to set the aspectrration to 169, then take the loaded title image and scale it to 16 cm : height of the free area? Or with 5:4 then to 125 mm : height of the free area? That would be just a curiosity for me now, if you could do something like that as an if-query.

Comment: @Snorlax You can force the image to have a certain size by setting both the height and width simultaneously: `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\dimexpr\paperheight-3cm\relax]{example-image-duck}}`

Comment: Would it make sense to crop the image? So instead of a strong distortion, that you scale it, either to an optimal height or width and then just cut off the excess?

Say, if I have a very long image, it's scaled to height like that, then theoretically it should be compressed to width. But instead of compressing it, then just trimming off the excess ends from the width. The same if you have a very tall image, that you scale it to the width and then cut off the top and bottom edges.

Comment: @Snorlax If you use `width=\paperwidth` the image will be cropped at the top if too tall. If you specify a height, the image will be cropped left and right if too wide.

Comment: @Snorlax I added a second approach which clips the image on all sides